# Icon of Button does not Update upon clicking

Tags: java, swing

Im trying to make a simple `Tic Tac Toe` game right now, i created a JFrame with the Grid Layout and added 9 buttons to it. Now uppon clicking one of those buttons i want to change the Icon of it to be either a cross or a circle, but it just doesnt do anything on click

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    if (e.getSource() == this)
    {
        if (counter%2 == 0)
        {
            ImageIcon cross = new ImageIcon("Cross.png");
            this.setIcon(cross);
        }
    
        if (counter%2 == 1)
        {
            ImageIcon circle = new ImageIcon("Circle.png");
            this.setIcon(circle);
        }
    
        counter++;
    }
}
```

[Project Structure here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PgNXZ.png)

The `actionPerformed` method does work with a simple `System.out.println()` statement

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: What is the intial value of `counter` and why `e.getSource()==this`?

Comment: Counter is just a static variable used to determine the state of which player is currently playing, thats not important tho since it is working with sout.

Comment: The thing with e.getSource() == this i saw on youtube and just copied it, but again it seems to be working

Comment: Any error you got in ide console while click on button

Comment: Nope no error __

Comment: problem is in condition  `evt.getSource()==this` return false...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to understand the meaning of `e.getSource()`, it's return all properties of button. Your condition `e.getSource() == this` return false that is a problem. You have to set image icon like `new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("path/img_name"))`.

Here down is generic code implementation so the logic will work on any of the nine buttons:

```
public void jButton1ActionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
   JButton button = (JButton)e.getSource();

    if(counter % 2 == 0)
    {
        button.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("Cross.png")));
    }
    else
    {
        button.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("Circle.png")));
    }

    counter++;
}
```

Comment: There is no need to check which button is clicked. Just get the source and set the icon. The same logic will apply for all 9 buttons so a generic listener can be shared for all the buttons.

Comment: Thank you for solving my problem! I do not yet entirely understand how the thing with e.getSource works but ill watch some more tutorials on that.